# jQuery $.ajax POST Request with IE 9 results empty array

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have a problem with my Coding, so in Firefox it works fine but in IE9 it only works for the first ~5 seconds. After that time i don't receive any POST Data anymore.

I want to load a PHP page via AJAX using the values of form inputs as POST variables.
The first 5 seconds i can receive the POST on the requested page but after that i only receive an empty string.

Here is my Code:

```
function reload_form(){
var data = $("#formularfelder").serialize()
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'content/formular.php',
        data: data,
        success: function(msg) {
             $("#form_container").html(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

Is it a bug of IE9 and is there a workaround available?

It would be awesome if you could help me! :)

******EDIT****

I found the reason for this issue at this post:

[Why does Internet Explorer not send HTTP post body on Ajax call after failure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796305/why-does-internet-explorer-not-send-http-post-body-on-ajax-call-after-failure)

IE runs into a keep-alive timout and doesn't send the body within the POST data anymore.

To workaround this problem I send a packet in regular time intervalls (equal to the keep-alive timeout) to the server to keep the keep-alive. This will cause a little bit traffic (~200 Bytes per refresh) but it's still a more practicable workaround then disabling the keep-alive in Apache.

This was the only solution I found for this problem

For someone with the same problem here's my refreshing Code for a keep-alive timeout of 5 seconds:

```
var updateDiv = function ()
{
    $.ajax({type: 'POST', url: 'timeout.php'});
    yourTimer = window.setTimeout(updateDiv, 5000);
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    var yourTimer = window.setTimeout(updateDiv, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Most likely you're hitting the error callback. Figure out why you're reaching the error callback and you'll have your answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Please change your Jquery version.
   I also faced the same problem in IE9 when I use jquery.js version 1.10.
   when try it with version 1.8 the problem was solved.

or

2. you can simply add this line in your code
   **$.support.cors = true;**

or

3.you can add jquery migrate js file to resolve this.
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js